# Doubt in derivation of bending of beam, It's about derivatives and intergration

Tags: classical-mechanics, calculus, rigid-body-dynamics, solid-mechanics, structural-beam

> [image]
>
> Radius of curvature of the beam in above picture is given as:
>
> $$ \frac{1}{R} = \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$$
>
> [image]

Please help me two points used as steps of a derivation in my book:

1. How was the radius of curvature of rod found?
2. How did eqtn 4-27 turn to eqtn 4-28? I see no dx, so I am confused how an integration could have been done.

Comment: Hi Sai! I have edited your question to make it more suitable for the site. Please from next time, present the question in mathjax and write all the equations which you see. Also ask maximum one question per post. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Recall that radius of curvature is defined as:

$$ R=  \frac{(1+y'^2)^{\frac32}}{y''}$$

In the particular case in the picture at $x=0$, $y'=0$ (due to choice of coordinate axes. Hence, $$ R = \frac{1}{y''}$$

2. They multiplied both side with $dx$ and integrated.

$$ W(l-x) = (YI_g) \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$$

Multiply both side by dx:

$$ W(l-x) dx = YI_g \frac{d^2 y }{dx^2} dx$$

And integrate.